# method not found Apache2::RequesUtil->request

Tags: perl, soap, apache2, mod-perl2

i have a small problem whith SOAP::Lite, 
When i try to run the following code, i have this error (Can’t locate object method “request” via package “Apache2::RequesUtil” at b.pl line 3) :

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use SOAP::Transport::HTTP2;
Apache2::RequestUtil->request();
```

any idea ?

Answer (score 1):

`use Apache2::RequestUtil ();`

Comment: @Wael - Your script is not complete and I was pointed to just one error I saw, as you cannot call `request` method/subroutine without `use` of particular package/module. You should google for some examples of code that would lead you to solution you need.

Comment: This code<br/>#!/usr/bin/perl
use Apache2::RequestUtil ();
Apache2::RequestUtil->request();